# FastLogger does not export Logger error with Yesod

Tags: haskell, ghc, cabal, yesod

I'm trying to install a Yesod project of mine via cabal, moving it from one machine to another. I'm getting the following error:

```
Foundation.hs:22:31: Module `System.Log.FastLogger' does not export `Logger'
```

That error is when I install without any bounds on the package versions. When  I use the bounds from the original project, `monad-logger` fails to install.

Any ideas on how to resolve this?

Comment: Did you start off by installing yesod-platform?

Comment: I tried that, and I get the same error. It's possible my foundation was generated using an older version of Yesod... should it be importing Logger from System.Log.FastLogger?

Answer (score 1):

Found the problem. I had `import System.Log.FastLogger (Logger)`, and I needed `import Yesod.Core.Types (Logger)`. Found the solution by looking at a fresh Foundation.hs generated by `yesod init`.

Comment: Yeah, there were some changes, but those should be rather easy to catch by creating a new scaffold and checking what's new in Application.hs and Foundation.hs